# How to express "friends that I only know them on internet" English?

Tags: word-request

I've come up with these options:

- Friends On Network (searched, this is not used very common)
- Friends Online (I think it's ambiguous, it can also mean the friends that are not offline but they're currently using the internet)

I think these are all inaccurate. How do native English speakers express that?

Comment: I don't think we have a very precise way to express this in English.  "Internet friends" is probably what I would say.

Comment: In context, **my online friends** or **an online acquaintance** would *not* be misconstrued by a native speaker; it would not be thought to mean "who is|are online at this moment".  The ambiguity you are concerned about occurs only when the phrase is lifted out of context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [*online friends*](https://medium.com/@elena_giacomoni/online-friends-vs-offline-friends-6554f74ead1f) is pretty popular, you can also use *internet friends* to avoid ambiguity.

> I might not have real friends in my life, but I have many *internet friends.*

A variation could be *friends on the Internet*

Another option is [*virtual friends*](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/relationships/love-sex/Virtual-vs-real-friends/articleshow/19740338.cms) vs *real friends.*

Comment: "Facebook friends" is also reasonably common & in the right hands, quite derogatory ;)

Comment: I feel a distinct connection to my **ELL friends**, some of whom I almost know by name.  :)